# Ubuntu 18.04 with DP connection doesn't recognize Dell Ultra Sharp UP3017

Tags: multiple-monitors, 18.04, dell

I recently clean installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have two monitors: Samsung and Dell. The samsung monitor is recognised with DBI cable, but Dell is not recognized (the first boot up menu appears, but soon after that it says no signal). The dell monitor doesn't have a dbi port (only DP and HDMI). My PC doesn't have a HDMI port. The monitor itself is functional because I can use the monitor for my laptop via HDMI.
Could anyone help me on this?

PC spec

- memory: 31.4GB
- processor: Intel core i7-4770CPU@3.4GHz
- Graphic llvmpipe(LLVM6.0,256 bits)
- GNOME: 3.28.1
- OS type 64-bit
- DISK 251GB

Video card information obtained with `sudo lshw -C display`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Caicos XTX [Radeon HD 8490 / R5 235X OEM]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e20000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
```